# removing border around an <img> tag and jQuery lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html:

```
<div class="compPhoto compPhoto3">
          <img class="lazy" src="" alt="" data-original="http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/c77631323e0411e394d322000a1f8c09_8.jpg" width="289" ;="" height="289">
</div>
```

I am actually using jQuery lazy load to load the images, however in the src tag I decided not to use an image, instead I just want to use a background. However then it gives me weird frame around the img:

[image]

I tried setting `border: none`, but it has no impact.
Any ideas on removing the border?

Comment: tried that and it still shows the gray border

Comment: try border:none!important

Comment: @SridharR that didn't work as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grey border will be shown by certain browsers to denote that the image cannot be found. Because of this, you will not be able to remove it using CSS.

You shouldn't really be using an `<img>` tag like this. If you just want to use background-images, why not use a `<div>` or another block tag.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Tim Ebenezer who wrote above. It is possible to hide the frame if the img tag is to add the style `"border-style: none"`, but it is imperative that the `src=""` tag is at least empty, then the frame is hidden in **Google Chrome, Firefox, EGDE, IE 10-11**! But unfortunately **it will not work for safari on MacOS and iOS.**